# Exclude database ID from DataTables search functionality

Tags: search, datatables

In a [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) table, one column contains cells with content of the format:

```
<a href="/Controller/Edit/26">Searchable and visible name</a>
```

Only the text between the tags is visible to the user, and I would like only this text to be exposed to the search functionality of DataTables. As it is now everything is searchable, including "href", "a", "<", "26", and so on. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in DataTables 1.9.4

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/14530/search-filtering-on-content#Item_2